# How can I prove $\frac{m+a}{m+a+l+b}$ is between $\frac{m}{m+l}$ and $\frac{a}{a+b}$?

Tags: proof-writing

Let $m,a,l,b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

How can I prove $\frac{m+a}{m+a+l+b}$ is between $\frac{m}{m+l}$ and $\frac{a}{a+b}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{a+c}{b+d}-\frac ab=\frac{bc-ad}{b(b+d)}
$$
and
$$
\frac{a+c}{b+d}-\frac cd=\frac{ad-bc}{d(b+d)}
$$

Comment: Hey can you explain more please

Comment: Note that the two differences have opposite signs since $b,d\gt0$.

Comment: @SathasivamK Yours is a special case of a [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)) so it has a vivid geometric proof (hint: the slope of the diagonal of a parallelogram lies between the sides).